# Customizing destroy for an STL vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl, allocator

I've read through quite a bit of reference material and a number of posts here on SO, but just can't seem to figure out how to "override" `destroy` for a `vector` of structures. This structure, `Package`, contains members of type `BSTR` that I need to call `SysFreeString`. I already have an inlined helper function to pass this `Package` type, but I need to call it.

My vector is declared as:

```
vector<Package, PackageAlloc> packages;
```

I've tried a number of ways based on reading and samples, and with the latest code get an error with the VC++ compiler:

> 'const _Package *std::_Wrap_alloc::address(const _Package &) const': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::_Container_proxy' to '_Package &'

My allocator is a specialization as declared below. I admit that while I've used STL a lot, allocators are not something I've worked with much.

```
struct PackageAlloc : public allocator<Package>
{
    template <class U>
    void destroy(Package* p)
    {
        ReleasePackage(p);
    }

    template <class U>
    struct rebind
    {
        typedef PackageAlloc other;
    };
};
```

I was hoping based on what I was reading from cppreference.com and some discussions here this would work, though most threads are customizing `allocate` and `deallocate`. Do those have to be installed? I keep reading about `allocator_traits` but don't see that it even gets used my MSVCRT 14.0 headers for vector.

More to the point, I was really looking for a working example of how I would customize just `destroy` or what my implementation is missing that either means my `destroy` is not called (i.e. it compiles but debugging yields no break) or why MSVC is erring. I don't need to override allocation of memory; I just want to make sure that elements within the vector are properly destroyed.

**Edit:** Of note, an array of `Package` structures is "returned" from a Win32-style COM method I own, following the convention of similar methods in our code base and because our immediate partners didn't want to deal with `SAFEARRAY` and allocation of new objects from an `IEnum`-style enumerator would be very inefficient (i.e. these are otherwise lightweight object). So while deallocation is left to the caller, I'm trying to provide helper functions and samples (such as this `vector` implementation) for more easily dealing with potential memory leaks.

Comment: Can your BSTRs be a class that frees their memory in their own destructors (CComBstr perhaps, unique_ptr with a custom deleter,  or one of your own)?  vector's destructor is responsible for destroying each item and deallocating it's own buffers - not releasing private memory of contained items. vector will destroy Packages which will destroy its members.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Just added a note that this structure is "returned" from a COM method using Win32-style array access. Using a bstr_t (I avoid ATL for all its overhead) in the structure would not really work.

Comment: So you are getting an array of structures which you copy into a vector (AddRef()'ing any COM interfaces).  I assume the original array is discarded. if this is so, you are allocating and copying your Packages.  Why not do the same thing using a unique_ptr with a custom deleter? your vector becomes a vector of unique_ptr<Package>...  The custom deleter can free memory and decrement refcounts if needed.

Comment: Drop `template <class U>`. As written, this function can never be called as `U` can never be deduced. Without it, your approach seems to [work for me](http://rextester.com/XXG74376), though I must say it still feels pretty sketchy.

Comment: @DavidThomas, these are not COM interfaces (too heavyweight for our partners' needs...though, maybe it's just easiest for clean-up). I don't think a unique_ptr would work since the vector wraps a raw array (the method declaration is just Package**), or would it? Seems it wouldn't since the raw vector data would then require an extra level of indirection for the unique_ptr's data.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, thanks. I'll try it. I only added them because it seems any callers would still pass a type argument that I figured wouldn't compile without a template. Offline, a friend of mine also mentioned that allocate and deallocate are required even though I can just return std::allocator<Package>::allocate(...) so I'll also give that a try.